# Keep exam question or question subpart and solution in the same page

Tags: page-breaking, exam

I will wish to have something like similar to `\filbreak`  which works for questions and choices by putting a `\filbreak` before each `\question` as described [HERE](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25116&start=10)  MWE below

To preventing page breaks between question and solutions in exam, apparently `\filbreak` does not work.  Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[answers, 10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 
\linespread{1}
 
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
 
 
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}\raggedright
 
\lipsum[1] \lipsum[1] \lipsum[1] \lipsum[1] \lipsum[1] \lipsum[2] 
 
 
 
\begin{questions}
 
\filbreak
\question Which of the following is an example of the correct answer?
 
 \filbreak 
\begin{choices}
\CorrectChoice first answer
\choice second answer
\choice third answer
\choice fourth answer
\choice fifth answer
\end{choices}

\filbreak
\question I am looking for getting question and  question parts not breaking
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[1]
\end{solution}


\filbreak 
\question Which of the following is an example of the correct answer?
\begin{choices}
\CorrectChoice first answer
\choice second answer
\choice third answer
\choice fourth answer
\choice fifth answer
\end{choices}


 

\filbreak 
\question Which of the following is an example of the correct answer?
\begin{choices}
\CorrectChoice first answer
\choice second answer
\choice third answer % This should be kept together with the first two choices
\choice fourth answer
\choice fifth answer
\end{choices}
 
 
\end{questions}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I see, question and to it belong answer are on the same pages. However, Your MWE gives the same result if you remove all `\filbreak` commands in it. What result you expect from your MWE?

Comment: @Zarko, thank you for pointing on the gap on MWE. I have made edits. To show the breaking. I will want the break after the  questions and the corresponding solution. that is Question and solution to be on the same page.

Comment: For better understanding work of `\filbreak` play with following MWE: `\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{showframe}  % Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{lipsum}     % For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\begin{questions}
    \filbreak
\question Which of the following is an example of the correct answer?
%    \filbreak
\begin{choices}
\choice first answer
\choice second answer
\CorrectChoice third answer
\choice fourth answer
\choice fifth answer
\end{choices} \end{questions}
\end{document}`

Comment: From results of testing MWE in above comment for different present of `\filbrak` command follows, that `\filbreak` not prevent breaking of text per se but rather suggest to LaTeX where break be more suitable as LaTeX algorithm intend to make it.

Comment: @Zarko, great but my question still remains how can I force question and solution to be in the same page?