# nopagebreak adds unwanted space between consecutive list environments

Tags: spacing, lists, page-breaking

Adding `\nopagebreak` between two consecutive list environments adds vertical space between them.  How can I prevent a page break without adding spurious vertical space?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.495\linewidth}
  \textbf{Allowing page breaks:}
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.495\linewidth}
  \textbf{Disallowing page breaks:}
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
  \nopagebreak
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Side by side comparison]

Comment: Is your `trivlist` always in `minipage`? If is, than it will not break  also without use of `\nopagebreak`.

Comment: penalties change the \addvspace, but `\nopagebreak` wouldn't work there  anyway. Preventing breaks around lists is quite hard as they insert break points in various places.

Comment: See, if the comments to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625914/keep-exam-question-or-question-subpart-and-solution-in-the-same-page can help you.

Comment: @Zarko: the minipages are only to show a side by side display

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the minipage is just for display (otherwise you can simply omit the `\nopagebreak` you can back up then re-insert glue after the penalty so the following list sees it. Inside the minipage you could remove the glue with `\unskip` but assuming this is really for the main vertical list leave it there but negative space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.495\linewidth}
  \textbf{Allowing page breaks:}
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.495\linewidth}
  \textbf{Disallowing page breaks:}
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
\ifnum\lastnodetype=11 % glue
\skip0=\lastskip
\vskip-\skip0
  \nopagebreak
\vskip\skip0
\else
\nopagebreak
\fi
  \begin{trivlist}\item AAA \end{trivlist}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```